# Unable to assert state flow value in view model

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

The view model is given below

```
class ClickRowViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val clickRowRepository: ClickRowRepository
): ViewModel() {

private val _clickRowsFlow = MutableStateFlow<List<ClickRow>>(mutableListOf())
val clickRowsFlow = _clickRowsFlow.asStateFlow()

fun fetchAndInitialiseClickRows() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        _clickRowsFlow.update {
            clickRowRepository.fetchClickRows()
        }
    }
}
```

}

My test is as follows:

[image: Unit test]

I am using `InstantTaskExecutorRule` as follows

```
    @get:Rule
    val instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
```

The actual value never resolves to the expected value even though `$result` seems to have two elements but the `actualValue` is an empty list. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

### Update

I tried to use the `first` terminal operator as well[image: Test with the first terminal operator] but the returned output returns an empty list.

### Update # 2

I tried `async` but I got the following error

```
kotlinx.coroutines.test.UncompletedCoroutinesError: After waiting for 60000 ms, the test coroutine is not completing, there were active child jobs: [DeferredCoroutine{Active}@a4a38f0]
at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTestCoroutine$3$3.invokeSuspend(TestBuilders.kt:342)
```

[image: Time Out Error]

**Update # 3**

This test passes in Android Studio, but fails using CLI

[image: Test passing in Android Studio]

Test failing in CLI

[image: Test failing in CLI]

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `toList` on a [`SharedFlow`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-shared-flow/) like that:

> **Shared flow never completes.** A call to `Flow.collect` on a shared flow never completes normally, and neither does a coroutine started by the `Flow.launchIn` function.

So calling `toList` will hang forever, because the flow never hits an end point where it says "ok that's all the elements", and `toList` needs to return a final value. Since `StateFlow` only contains one element at a time anyway, and you're not collecting over a period of time, you probably just want `take(1).toList()`.

Or use `first()` if you don't want the wrapping list, which it seems you don't - each element in the `StateFlow` is a `List<ClickRow>`, which is what `clickRowRepository.fetchClickRows()` returns too. So `expectedValue` is a `List<ClickRow>`, whereas `actualValue` is a `List<List<ClickRow>>` - so they wouldn't match anyway!

---

*edit* your update (using `first()`) has a couple of issues.

First of all, the `clickRowsFlow` `StateFlow` in your ViewModel *only* updates when you call `fetchAndInitialiseClickRows()`, because that's what fetches a value and sets it on the `StateFlow`. You're not calling that in your second example, so it won't update.

Second, that `StateFlow` is going to go through two state values, right? The first is the initial empty list, the second is the row contents you get back from the repo. So when you access that `StateFlow`, it either needs to be *after* the update has happened, or (better) you need to ignore the *first* state and only return the *second* one:

```
val actualValue = clickRowViewModel.clickRowsFlow
    .drop(1) // ignore the initial state
    .first() // then take the first result after that

// start the update -after- setting up the flow collection,
// so there's no race condition to worry about
clickRowsViewModel.fetchAndInitialiseClickRows()
```

This way, you subscribe to the `StateFlow` and immediately get (and drop) the initial state. Then when the update happens, it should push another value to the subscriber, which takes that `first` new value as its final result.

---

But there's another complication - because `fetchAndInitialiseClickRows()` kicks off *its own coroutine* and returns immediately, that means the *fetch-and-update* task is running asynchronously. You need to give it time to finish, before you start asserting any results from it.

One option is to start the coroutine and then block waiting for the result to show up:

```
// start the update
clickRowsViewModel.fetchAndInitialiseClickRows()

// run the collection as a blocking operation, which completes when you get
// that second result
val actualValue = clickRowViewModel.clickRowsFlow
    .drop(1)
    .first()
```

This works *so long as `fetchAndInitialiseClickRows` doesn't complete immediately*. That consumer chain up there *requires* at least two items to be produced **while it's subscribed** - if it never gets to see the initial state, it'll hang waiting for that second (really a third) value that's never coming. This introduces a race condition and even if it's "probably fine in practice" it still makes the test brittle.

Your other option is to subscribe first, using a coroutine so that execution can continue, and *then* start the update - that way the subscriber can see the initial state, and then the update that arrives later:

```
// async is like launch, but it returns a `Deferred` that produces a result later
val actualValue = async {
    clickRowViewModel.clickRowsFlow
        .drop(1)
        .first()
}

// now you can start the update
clickRowsViewModel.fetchAndInitialiseClickRows()

// then use `await` to block until the result is available
assertEquals(expected, actualValue.await())
```

---

You **always** need to make sure you handle waiting on your coroutines, otherwise the test could finish early (i.e. you do your asserting before the results are in). Like in your first example, you're launching a coroutine to populate your list, but not ensuring that has time to complete before you check the list's contents.

In that case you'd have to do something like `advanceUntilIdle()` - [have a look at this section on testing coroutines](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/test#standardtestdispatcher), it shows you some ways to wait on them. This might also work for the one you're launching with `fetchAndInitialiseClickRows` (since it says it waits for other coroutines on the scheduler, not the same scope) but I'm not really familiar with it, you could look into it if you like!

Comment: I tried using toList operator, but it populates a list of empty list so it does not work for me.

Comment: @Kartik I'm guessing you mean you tried `first()` since that's what you've edited into your question - I've added to my answer since there's uh a fair bit of explanation

Comment: I tried your approach but the test fails for me.